Session is not updating on server side in Next-Auth
callbacks:{
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
        return {...token, ...user}
    },

    async session({session, token, user}) {
        console.log("Token: ",token)
        session.user.token = token;
        return session;

    },

This is callback code for updating session and token. It is updating session in client side perfectly but not able to update on Server Side. There are only 3 value i am getting on server side {name, email and image}
I dont know how to fix this problem.
